# Is there a way to confirm whether SSL/TSL termination is working or not , in Application Gateway in Azure

Tags: azure, encryption, ssl-certificate, azure-application-gateway

So , i added the SSL/TSL certificate in the listener part of the application gateway and i am curious to whether i get the encrypted/decrypted data or not.My main question is , can i physically see whether the requests are being encrypted/decrypted by application gateway?.Thank you.

Comment: if a it is able to serve https requests without any error then I guess it is doing the job well.

Comment: but i need a more visual solution , like i can see the result.

Comment: Use tcpdump/wireshark to see the encrypted traffic. But really, if it works it works. Use two independent tools -- say, a browser and curl -- if you don't trust one of them (but why wouldn't you?)